# Estimating function with Gaussian Procceses

Tags: normal-distribution, gaussian-process, approximation

I do not have strong math background, but I am trying to understand Gaussian Processes by example using the lecture **Machine learning - Introduction to Gaussian processes** by **Nando de Freitas**. Here is the [**link to a relevant slide**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4vGiHC35j9s&t=3443s).

Given the following data:

$$f(1.02) = 0.79$$
$$f(1.99) = 0.94$$
$$f(4.04) = 0.65$$

I want to estimate $f(3) \pm \sigma$.

I am using Gaussian Kernel:

$$K(x_1,x_2) = \sigma * exp\Biggl(\frac{-(x_1-x_2)^2}{2l}\Biggr)$$
with parameters $\sigma = 1.5$ and $l = 5$.

According to the lecture, I need to compute the following matrix:

$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
K & K_* \\
K^T_* & K_{**} 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

So, $\mu$ and $\sigma$ can be computed:

$$\mu = K^T_* * K^{-1} * f$$
$$\sigma = -K^T_* * K^{-1} * K_* + K_{**}$$

I have computed the matrix:

$$
K =
\begin{bmatrix} 
1.500 & 1.365 & 0.603 \\
1.365 & 1.500 & 0.985 \\
0.603 & 0.985 & 1.500 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
K_* =
\begin{bmatrix} 
1.014 \\
1.355 \\
1.346 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$K^T_{*} = [1.014,1.355,1.346]$$

$$K_{**} = [1.500]$$

I got a reasonable value for $\mu = 0.8878$, but apparently $\sigma = 0.0079$ is way too small. I do not understand what I am doing wrong.

Here is my [calculations](https://lcab-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/pkoryakin_powerhub_com/ETy-AyW79iRGl11rCUOIpgoBQkh-OanEoWLiKZRhHUw-DQ?e=W7chNR) done in Excel.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly I checked the calculations and they seemed correct.

However, you seem to be using it as purely an interpolation method blindly. Interpolation passes exactly through the points and if this is the case than your length scale will likely be too large ($l$).

How one usually uses a GP you select a kernel based on some sensible understanding of the system. Observations generally speaking have Gaussian independent identically distributed (iid) noise which means adding some value to the diagonal elements of the covariance matrix. Finally, this new noise parameter, along with the length-scale and output noise ($l,s$), must be optimised with respect to the log marginal likelihood of the GP. Basically you need to 'fit' the GP to the data.

Comment: Thank you sir! I have changed length and sigma parameters for the kernel to 1 and got much more reasonable values.

Comment: @koryakinp you really shouldn't be doing this by hand. We usually use an optimiser.

Comment: I am not going to understand how it works, unless I do it by hand.

Comment: @koryakinp that is completely fair!